# Recurrence relation for Number of permutations with constraints of a combination of symbols

Tags: permutations

Suppose we have $m+n$ symbols out which $m$ are identical and $n$  are distinct. It is required  to find the number of permutations of these $m+n$ symbols such that no two identical symbols  are together. I tried to solve it through   the help of  of a recurrence relation. .My reasoning as follows:

If $f(m,n)$ is the requisite no of permutations  the following  things are obvious :
$$f(1,1)=2$$
$$f(1,n)=(n+1)!$$ and similar such base conditions.
Now in the general case  the first symbol can be either one among the $m$ identical symbols or it can be one of the  $n$  different symbols .This means we have the following  recurrence relation
$$f(m,n)=n{f(m-1,n-1)+nf(m,n-1)}$$. In particular what is the value of $f(4,6)$

Is my reasoning and hence the above recurrence relation correct ?I would be greatly thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your recurrence relation looks correct. You need to specify that $f(1, 0) = 1$ in your base case, though.

As an aside, you might want to show that, in general, $$f(m, n) = \binom{n + 1}{m}\times n!$$

Hints for obtaining the general formula -

1. In how many ways can you arrange $n$ distinct items?
2. Note that arranging $n$ items creates $n + 1$ new spots (i.e. at the ends and between every two items). In how many ways can you choose $m$ spots?
3. In how many ways can you arrange $m$ identical items?

Comment: when  we try to evaluate $f(2,1) $ it  comes out to be $f(1,1)+f(2,0)=2+0=2 $ but a direct observation tells us that $f(2,1)=1 $ as in the  $a,b,a$.So what is wrong with the recurrence relation.And please would u give some hint as to how we  can derive the formula u mentioned for $f(m,n)$

Comment: @sajjadveeri for the first question, please recheck your work. For the second, I've added hints.

Comment: Thank u i got it..